# How to input or insert one name with more products into the database using the power and magic of php?

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to input one name with more products. the scenario here is when I

> input the Name:_______________ Product:______________
>   Product:_______________.

It will the be inserted into the database and it will display like this:

```
 Johnny | Iphone 
 Johnny | Windows Phone
```

Here's my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name_txt[]" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
            <input type="reset" name="submit" value="clear" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php   

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include 'db.php';

    foreach($_POST['product_name_txt'] as $row => $value){

        $name=$_POST['name_txt'][$row];
        $product=$_POST['product_name_txt'][$row];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO request(p_name, product_name) VALUES ('$name','$product')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
     }
   }    
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your code?

Comment: logical error please take a look at the link image [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sphw2td1kq7alzs/logical_error.PNG?dl=0 )

Answer (score 2):

First, since there's only one name you should use `name_txt` instead of `name_txt[]`.And second, for your products use `implode()` function to join the array elements with a string, and then perform your `INSERT` operation.

Change this

```
<td><input type="text" name="name_txt[]" /></td>
```

to

```
<td><input type="text" name="name_txt" /></td>
```

And do your form processing like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){      
    include 'db.php';
    $name=$_POST['name_txt'];
    $products = implode(" ", $_POST['product_name_txt']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO request(p_name, product_name) VALUES ('$name','$products')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct but you just need to modify this.

```
<td><input type="text" name="name_txt" /></td>
```

```
$name = $_POST['name_txt'];
$products = $_POST['product_name_txt']; 

foreach($products as $value){
$sql = "INSERT INTO request(p_name, product_name) VALUES ('$name','$value')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
{
 echo "New record created successfully"; }
 else { 
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
}
}
```